# FragmentActivity: "cover" content with a fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-fragments

I have a FragmentActivity with a ListView inside (filled in onCreate() ). Now i would that when user tap on e ListView element a custom Fragment appear on current FragmentActivity and  "hide" all FragmentActivity content (in this case that ListView). It's possible to do it, or i need to create a fragment also for show ListView?

```
public class MyActivity extends FragmentActivity {
private ArrayList<Object> list;
private FragmentManager fragmentManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mylaytou);

    list = PrincipalActivity.getMatchesList();

    ListView list = (ListView) this
            .findViewById(R.id.listView);
    ArrayAdapter<Object> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Object>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            fragmentManager = MyActivity.this
                    .getSupportFragmentManager();
            MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment((Object) arg0
                    .getItemAtPosition(arg2));

            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
                    .beginTransaction();

            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.ViewGroup, fragment).commit();

        }

    });

}
```

Comment: It would be better if you post the code you tried

Comment: edited message with code

Comment: have you tried replace instead of add in begin transaction.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to hide the list view then it's better to follow the [single pane](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/tablets-and-handsets.html#Fragments) approach. Otherwise it's better to start a whole new activity.

Following the first approach you'll have to create 2 fragments and use [FragmentTransaction](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html) to [replace](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#replace%28int,%20android.app.Fragment,%20java.lang.String%29) the old fragment with the new one.